# Detecting hover over QComboBox items in PyQt6/PySide6

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qcombobox

Here is an example code

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QEvent
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout
import sys


class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.addItem('Item 1')
        self.combo_box.addItem('Item 2')
        self.combo_box.addItem('Item 3')
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)

        self.combo_box.installEventFilter(self)


    def eventFilter(self, obj, ev):
        if ev.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            print('here is suppossed to be item that I hovered over')
        return super().eventFilter(obj, ev)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWidget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

What I want to do is to access the item (**as an object**) of the dropdown list of combo box, when hovering over it.

For example - I click on the combox, I hover my cursor over "Item 2" and I can apply animation of color change transition to it (which is not possible through stylesheets).

I've tried researching how to access QComboBox items'/children' signals with **[`highlighted`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QComboBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox.highlighted)**however with no luck

Comment: Why not just do e.g. `self.combo_box.highlighted.connect(print)`?

Comment: I get the feeling that the hover detection isn't the real problem here. The `highlighted` signal will do that. It seems more an issue of "How to get the `QStandardItem` from the index number?". Am I correct with this assessment?

Comment: It doesn't seem especially difficult to work out how to use the index sent by the `highlighted` signal. The [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#public-functions) class provides multiple APIs that take an index, as does the [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstandarditemmodel.html#public-functions) class. So you can simply do e.g. `item = self.combo_box.model().item(index)`.

Comment: The dropdown popup is a related but completely different widget. Installing an event filter on the combobox to get events of its popup is effective just as it would be installing an event filter on a window and hoping to get mouse events on a button inside it. Use the `highlighted` signal as written above, otherwise install the event filter on the combo's [`view()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#view) (or, better, its `viewport()`).